# Whats happend if i use the same database to connect two websites?

Tags: database

I have a websites agriculture related with info's.
The script is very limited and do not allow me to create a classified section to my website, so, i need to create another one.

For the new website (created on subdomain, but with the same script), if i use the same database, user accounts will be kept?

In fact, that's what interests me. My users from the info's site automatically keep their accounts on the classified site, without the need for another account.
I just want to keep user accounts and nothing else.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyP7z.png)

Answer (score 1):

The database should keep all of the data in it regardless of how many sites its connected to, however all of said sites can now see and edit it.